# How can I separate a pandas dataframe based on time differences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I pulled my group's text messages and it looks something like the table below (excluding the third column).

**How can I separate the first conversation from the second based on time and assign each message to a conversation_id?**

If it helps, I'm comfortable assuming that if any message hasn't been responded to in an hour, the next message starts a new conversation.

If given the first the two columns, I'd ideally be able to figure out the third across nearly 45,000 messages with varying conversation lengths.

Once I have our text messages split into conversations, I think I could train a chatbot to participate in our chats! I don't know what I'm doing here so I'd appreciate any help :)

```
| created_at          | message                              | conversation_id |
| 2018-07-03 02:12:33 | knock knock                          | 1               |
| 2018-07-03 02:12:35 | who's there                          | 1               |
| 2018-07-03 02:12:40 | Europe                               | 1               |
| 2018-07-03 02:12:45 | Europe who?                          | 1               |
| 2018-07-03 02:12:48 | No - you're a poo                    | 1               |
| 2018-07-03 03:15:17 | knock knock                          | 2               |
| 2018-07-03 03:15:20 | who's there                          | 2               |
| 2018-07-03 03:15:23 | the KGB                              | 2               |
| 2018-07-03 03:15:28 | the KGB who?                         | 2               |
| 2018-07-03 03:15:33 | SLAP the KGB will ask the questions! | 2               |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. I don't think you can improve much upon iterating through the dataframe in order to assign the ID's, since they're based on a chained connection to previous values in the column:

```
d = {"created_at": pd.to_datetime(["2018-07-03 02:12:33", "2018-07-03 02:12:35","2018-07-03 02:12:40","2018-07-03 02:12:45","2018-07-03 02:12:48","2018-07-03 03:15:17","2018-07-03 03:15:20","2018-07-03 03:15:23","2018-07-03 03:15:28","2018-07-03 03:15:33","2018-08-03 09:00:00","2018-09-03 10:15:00"]),
     "message": ["knock knock","who's there","Europe","Europe who?","No - you're a poo","knock knock","who's there","the KGB","the KGB who?","SLAP the KGB will ask q's!","Hello?","Hello, again?"]}
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#60mins in secs
thresh = 60*60

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#Creating time delta from previous message
df["delta"] = df["created_at"].diff().fillna(0).dt.total_seconds()

#Normalising delta based on threshold as a flag for new convos
df["id"] = np.where(df["delta"] < thresh, 0, 1)
df = df.drop(["delta"], axis=1)

#Assigning ID's to each convo
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'id'] += df.loc[i-1, 'id']
```

```
print(df)

            created_at                     message  id
0  2018-07-03 02:12:33                 knock knock   0
1  2018-07-03 02:12:35                 who's there   0
2  2018-07-03 02:12:40                      Europe   0
3  2018-07-03 02:12:45                 Europe who?   0
4  2018-07-03 02:12:48           No - you're a poo   0
5  2018-07-03 03:15:17                 knock knock   1
6  2018-07-03 03:15:20                 who's there   1
7  2018-07-03 03:15:23                     the KGB   1
8  2018-07-03 03:15:28                the KGB who?   1
9  2018-07-03 03:15:33  SLAP the KGB will ask q's!   1
10 2018-08-03 09:00:00                      Hello?   2
11 2018-09-03 10:15:00               Hello, again?   3
```

Comment: Nice - this worked for me! Thank you so much! Going through 45K messages was pretty quick too!